# Setting values in a python dictionary

Tags: python-3.x

When it comes to declaring new values in a python dictionary how come this works:

```
app_dict = {}
app_dict['properties'] = { "name": "test" }
```

But something like this doesn't: (keyerror)

```
app_dict = {}
app_dict['properties']['version'] = {"name":"dino"}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

for the first part

```
app_dict = {}
app_dict['properties'] = { "name": "test" }
```

if a key doesn't exist, it will be created, you initially defined `app_dict = {}` as a dictionary object, hence `app_dict['properties'] = { "name": "test" }` is valid because it created a `properties` key and assigned the content as another dictionary `{'name': 'test'}`

for the second part

```
app_dict = {}
app_dict['properties']['version'] = {"name":"dino"}
```

the `app_dict['properties']` doesn't exist yet so it's not a dictionary , hence assigning `app_dict['properties']['version'] = {"name":"dino"}` will thrown an error `KeyError: 'properties'`.

if you have done it this way

```
app_dict = {}
app_dict['properties'] = { "name": "test" }
app_dict['properties']['version'] = {"name":"dino"}
```

This would have worked , because `app_dict['properties']` is already created as it's declared as a dictionary , hence `app_dict['properties']['version'] = {"name":"dino"}` will only create a key in the dictionary assigning it to another dictionary

Comment: Thanks, this seemed to answer the issue I was having!